# Disable back/forward button in web browser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my app, I have a [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Beneath it, I have a toolbar with the back and forward buttons to control the browser. How do I disable the back button when the user is on the initial page and disable the forward button when the user is on the most recent page? Looking at the [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol, I don't see any callbacks that tell me the position of the user in their browser history.

It should look like Safari's toolbar:

[image]

**Edit:** I figured out the detection part, but I can't figure out the disabling part. My buttons always remain at full opacity and are tappable even when `NSLog` prints out `0` for `canGoBack` or `canGoForward`.

.h

```
@interface VeetleViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    UIWebView* webView;
    UIBarButtonItem* buttonBack;
    UIBarButtonItem* buttonForward;
    UIActivityIndicatorView* activityIndicator;
}

- (void)activityIndicatorStop;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView* webView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem* buttonBack;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem* buttonForward;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView* activityIndicator;

@end
```

.m

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"canGoBack:%d canGoForward:%d", self.webView.canGoBack, self.webView.canGoForward); 

    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

    if (self.webView.canGoBack) {
        self.buttonBack.enabled = YES;
    } else {
        self.buttonBack.enabled = NO;
    }

    if (self.webView.canGoForward) {
        self.buttonForward.enabled = YES;
    } else {
        self.buttonForward.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's properties on the UIWebView, not the delegate.

see: canGoBack and canGoForward.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/canGoBack

Comment: thanks for this. Now I can't figure out how to disable my buttons. I edited my post describing the issue.

Comment: Nevermind. I forgot to link the IBOutlet. It should have thrown an error, but didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement in one of the delegate methods of web view:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [backbutton setEnabled:[webView canGoBack]];
    [fwdbutton setEnabled:[webView canGoForward]];
}
```